# How to trigger jquery plugins after ajax has loaded a page in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

After all links in Google search results being purple and me being frustrated since couple of hours I decided to ask you guys to help me with the problem.

On my home page in WordPress, a loop generates list with all posts titles on the blog. To improve website loading time, I decided to go with AJAX. Instead of loading all content at once, you click the title of certain post to display its cotnent below. Simply, when you click it POSTs the id of the post (taken from attribute tag) to the ajax.php file (being WordPress template with a loop to display content ... ). When the content is read out, it gets displayed on the front end.

Problem are plugins. As they are not re-fired after content loads (DOM changes). Obviously, I don't want the solution that I add every single plugin I installed to AJAX callback, because it is not the way it should be. I want it automated. WordPress is meant to be simple and easy to manage (even from developers point of view).

I already tried with live(), livequery() - the plugin, listen() - the plugin .. and tried to change my ajax script to be more the WordPress way (using admin-ajax.php) and everytime result is the same - it doesnt work.

By plugins I mean for example: Syntax Highlighter, Social Share Buttons or FancyBox / Lightbox for images... Even if I add plugin's function to the ajax loop to display it manually it still fails...

I suspect I may use live() functions a bit wrong or something ... anyway this is my code:

**Front-end loop (index.php)**

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>   
    <article>
        <div class="fake">
            <div class="header" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <span class="tags">
                    <?php
                      $posttags = get_the_tags();
                      if ($posttags) {
                        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                          echo $tag->name . ', '; 
                        }
                      }
                    ?>
                </span>
                <span class="post_no">#<?=$published?></span>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </article>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Fragment of AJAX I use:**

```
$('.header').live('click',function() {
        var content = $(this).parent().parent().find('.content');
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        content.load("http://localhost/simpleecode/ajax/",{id:post_id}).delay(800).slideDown('slow');});
```

**Template with loop for AJAX:**

```
<?php $post = get_post($_POST['id']); ?>
<?php if ($post) : ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

I think you may like link to the dev website to check out the DOM and files for your own too (I used shortlink because it is dev site and I don't want it to be public anyhow):

http://bit.ly/Oa6hWH

Hope you will have idea on how to do this :S

Comment: Er, it IS public now, anyway :D

Comment: It is still hidden from spider bots and I mean the actual URL... nevermind :) It is not so important here man :)

Comment: using live will only help new headers added to the page being linked to your click event handler... it has nothing to do with how the plugins are attached to your page elements... depends on how the plugins were attached to your page elements in the first place... if any plugin did not use live or on, you have no choice but to attach the new page element to the plugin again on ajax load

Answer (score 3):

Use the success/complete callback of AJAX request to call plugins for html that is new to the DOM.

```
content.load("http://localhost/simpleecode/ajax/",{id:post_id}, function(){
     /* new html now exists*/
    $(this).find('.classThatNeedsPlugin').somePlugin();

}).delay(800).slideDown('slow');
```

**[jQuery API - load() method docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

If plugins have any dimension sensitive code in them you may need to alter this to call a plugin in the callback of the animation

EDIT: Rather than use delay() to setup the animation, call the animation within the same success callback, the html will be ready then

```
content.load("http://localhost/simpleecode/ajax/",{id:post_id}, function(){
     /* new html now exists*/
    $(this).find('.classThatNeedsPlugin').somePlugin().slideDown('slow');      

});
```

**Edit2 Alternate methods: jQuery deferred object methods.**

You can also use deferred to set up your ajax callbacks.

```
var jqXhr= content.load("http://localhost/simpleecode/ajax/",{id:post_id});
$.when( jqXhr).then( /* plugin function */);
```

**OR custom events**

```
/* on page load*/
$('#myTable').on('myCustomEventName', function(){
     $(this).doPlugins();
}).trigger('myCustomEventName');

/* ajax callback*/
content.load("http://localhost/simpleecode/ajax/",{id:post_id}, function(){
     $('#myTable').trigger('myCustomEventName')

})
```

Comment: I have written I don't want to use callback in Ajax. I would prefer it to be automated, but if that is the only solution... how do I know what functions a plugin uses to fire itself?

Comment: if you are hoping for a holy grail like `live()` , there isn't one. Majority of plugins manipulate html, or bind custom events or data, or have other reasons that the html must exist. You can wrap your plugin calls in functions that can be used both on page load and ajax load. Depends on the page and plugins being used

Comment: Ok so what you mean guys is all I can do about the problem is find triggering jquery function for each plugin and insert it into callback in load() function?

Comment: I added a couple more ways that you can set it up, but no matter what, the actual plugin call almost always has to be made after the new html loads

Comment: think of it this way.... how could a syntax highlighter highlight code that doesn't exist?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) Wish me luck and (I hope) see you when site is live :)